# Fixing up C++XX synonyms

Tags: discussion, status-declined, synonym-request

Now that [ISO/IEC 14882:2017](https://www.iso.org/standard/68564.html) is officially published, we should treat [c++17](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17) as the master and synonymize [c++1z](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b1z) to it (currently they are synonymized in the other direction).

While we are at this, we should probably synonymize [c++20](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b20) to [c++2a](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b2a) until that standard is published per the previous practice.

Answer (score 6):

> we should probably synonymize [c++20](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b20) to [c++2a](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b2a) until that standard is published per the previous practice.

No, we absolutely should not.

C++0x was coined and used by actual C++ standards committee members, so it made sense to refer to it with that tag until C++11 actually came out in 2011. Also, C++11's development cycle was labored and torturous, with no actual planned release date target. Well, technically it had a planned one (2009) but it slipped.

However, C++14 and C++17 did not have that. By that point, the committee had made it their mission to have regular releases of C++, come hell or high water. As such, committee members routinely referred to C++14 and C++17 as exactly that. Search through the ISO papers, and while you'll find lots of references to C++0x, you'll find almost none for C++1y and even fewer for C++1z.

Indeed, the primary references to C++1y and C++1z you find out there are in compiler options. GCC and Clang use those as their option for unfinished standards; once they formally support the actual published standard, they add an option that means "the actual published standard".

The committee has proven over 2 release cycles that they can deliver on time (whether you believe they've delivered enough features is up to you, but they've been on time). So let's stop using these made up terms.

The ISO C++ standardization committee intends to release a C++ standard in 2020. They have shown that they can do so. There are zero references in papers to C++2a, while there are many references to C++20.

It is C++20. If the committee misses the date, then we can create a C++21 or whatever synonym and fix it later. But for now, that is what it ought to be.